# How can I get output parameter to stored procedure in POCO?

Tags: c++, mysql, poco-libraries

I'm using to poco libraries version 1.4.6

I want make program to connecting database, call stored procedure and get out parameters.

Firstly, I select value like this.

```
conn.Connect(host, user, password, db);
Poco::Data::Session* session = conn.Ptr();

int myNum;
std::string myStr;
*session << "SELECT `my_number`, `my_string` FROM `my_table`;",
    Poco::Data::into(myNum),
    Poco::Data::into(myStr),
    Poco::Data::now;
```

That was available.

I want to call stored procedure and get output parameter value. so wrote like this.

```
// `my_sp` was simple stored procedure like this.
// `my_sp`(in inum int, in istr varchar(50), out onum int, out ostr varchar(50))
//     SET onum = inum;
//     SET ostr = istr;
int inNum, outNum;
std::string inStr, outStr;
*session << "CALL `my_sp`(?,?,?,?);",
    Poco::Data::use(inNum),
    Poco::Data::use(inStr),
    Poco::Data::into(outNum),
    Poco::Data::into(outStr),
    Poco::Data::now;
```

But it was not available.

I tried like that.

```
*session << "CALL `my_sp`(1234, \'abcd\', @o_num, @o_str);",
    Poco::Data::now;

*session << "SELECT @o_num;",
    Poco::Data::into(outNum),
    Poco::Data::now;

//*session << "SELECT @o_num, @o_str;",
//    Poco::Data::into(outNum),
//    Poco::Data::into(outStr),
//    Poco::Data::now;
```

I can get out number through select. But i can't get out string. if I select outStr, throw exception.

```
[MySQL]: [Comment]: mysql_stmt_fetch error  [mysql_stmt_error]:     [mysql_stmt_errno]: 0   [mysql_stmt_sqlstate]: 00000    [statemnt]: SELECT @o_num, @o_str;
```

Why throw exception? I don't understand. Because I'm not goot at English.

I tried find another question like me. but other user was unlike me.

I think that reason was I'm not good at English. so hard to learn poco-document.

I want using stored procedure and get output parameter.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stored procedures are not supported in 1.4.x. You should use a 1.5.x release and Data::ODBC back-end for full stored procedure I/O support.